# Update table if value is in select from another table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: rec_new_license and recruit_zips.

recruit_zips contains 'zip_code' and 'office_name' and contains zip codes and office names.

rec_new_license contains a field 'zip' and a field 'recruit_office'. 
This table needs to have the 'recruit_office' field updated if the value in 'zip' matches 'zip_code' in the recruit_zips table and 'office_name' matches 'Spring Hill'.

Neither query performs the task or fails with an error. Am I going about this wrong?

```
$sql = "UPDATE rec_new_license 
SET recruit_office = 'Spring Hill' 
WHERE zip IN 
( 
 SELECT zip_code FROM recruit_zips 
 WHERE office_name = 'Spring Hill'
)";

$results = $mysqli->query($sql);
```

Also tried:

```
$sql = "UPDATE rec_new_license t1
  JOIN recruit_zips t2
    ON t1.zip = t2.zip_code
    WHERE t2.office_name = 'Spring Hill'
SET t1.recruit_office = 'Spring Hill'
";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. It must be:

```
$sql = "UPDATE rec_new_license t1
  JOIN recruit_zips t2
    ON t1.zip = t2.zip_code
    SET t1.recruit_office = 'Spring Hill'
    WHERE t2.office_name = 'Spring Hill'
";
```

Comment: That worked. Also needed to add:
ON t1.zip COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci = t2.zip_code
Thanks!